# Bash script working with second column from txt but keep first column in result as relevant

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script to ease a process with IP information gathering.
Right now I have made a script which runs throught the one column of IP address in multiple files, looks for geo and host information and stores it to a new file.

What would be nice is also to have a script that generates a result from files with a 3 columns - date, time, ip address. Separator is space.
I tried this an that but no. I am a total newbie :)

This is my original script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
find *.txt -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file;
do
        for  i in $( cat "$file")
        do echo -e "$i,"$( geoiplookup -f "/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat" $i | cut -d' ' -f6,8-9)" "$(nslookup $i | grep name | awk '{print $4}')"" >> "res/res-"$file".txt";
        done
done
```

Input file example

```
2014-03-06 12:13:27     213.102.145.172
2014-03-06 12:18:24     83.177.253.118
2014-03-25 15:42:01     213.102.155.173
2014-03-25 15:55:47     213.101.185.223
2014-03-26 15:21:43     90.130.182.2
```

Can you please help me on this?

Comment: Please update question with expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what the current code is attempting to do, but here is a hopefully useful refactoring which could be at least a starting point.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
find *.txt -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file;
do
    while read date time ip; do
        geo=$(geoiplookup -f "/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat" "$ip" |
             cut -d' ' -f6,8-9)
        addr=$(nslookup "$ip" | awk '/name/ {print $4}')
        #addr=$(dig +short -x "$ip")
        echo "$ip $geo $addr"
    done <"$file" >"res/res-$file.txt"
done
```

My copy of `nslookup` does not output four fields but I assume that part of your script is correct.  The output from `dig +short` is better suitable for machine processing, so maybe switch to that instead.  Perhaps `geoiplookup` also offers an option to output machine-readable results, or maybe there is an alternative interface which does.

I assume it was a mistake that your script would output partially comma-separated, partially whitespace-separated results, so I changed that, too.  Maybe you should use CSV or JSON instead if you intend for other tools to be able to read this output.

Trying to generate a file named `res/res-$file.txt` will only work if `file` is not in any subdirectory, so I'm guessing you will want to fix that with `basename`; or perhaps the `find` loop should be replaced with a simple `for file in *.txt` instead.

Comment: Just interesting, why the result file when opened on windows is not a multiline formated?

Comment: Ugh.  Perhaps it would be better to use a proper text editor on Windows if you really need to use the file there.